# How to send (AJAX) POST data to url and redirect to the same url with data?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

```
jQuery(".w").click(function() {
    var id =jQuery(this).attr('id');

    var location="http://localhost:8888/Admin/description/description.php";
    $.ajax({
        url: location,
        type:'POST',
        data:{data:id}
    });
});
```

I want to redirect to location along with data, can't use form in my case

Comment: Can you explain *why* you can't use a form?

Comment: Because I am using an image on click , by using Jquery I am taking the attribute and linking to the php url

Comment: You can still use an image click to submit a form. See [`<input type="image">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/image)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any reason to involve JavaScript in this at all.

If you want to click on an image and submit data via POST, simply use something like

```
<form method="post" action="http://localhost:8888/Admin/description/description.php">
  <input type="image" name="data" value="your-id-value"
         src="/url/of/some/image">
</form>
```

---

If that *really* doesn't float your boat, you could approach it like this...

```
jQuery('.w').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // just in case
  const form = document.createElement('form')
  form.method = 'POST'
  form.action = 'http://localhost:8888/Admin/description/description.php'
  const input = document.createElement('input')
  input.type = 'hidden'
  input.name = 'data'
  input.value = this.id
  form.appendChild(input)
  form.submit()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    $(".w").click(function(){
           var id =jQuery(this).attr('id');
    var location="http://localhost:8888/Admin/description/description.php";
    $.ajax({
    url: location,
    type:'POST',
    data:{data:id},
    success: function(data){
    alert(data.data);
    }
    });
    });
```

add the success attribute of ajax